# Adjust View Height and Width accordingly

Tags: android, xml

I have the following xml implementation. However, as you see in the following, heights and widths are hard coded, and even though that values work on Nexus 10. However it does not work properly on Nexus 7.

I need to know is there a way to handle it something like percentage?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:background="#0000FF">
<View
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
<View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:background="#00FF0000"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/view2"
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/view2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
 <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view1"
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:background="#00FF0000"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout
```

Here is the layout design

[image]

The reason that I do not want to convert relativelayout to linear layout, because I add a transparent view on the top of `view2` and `view 4` to receive gesture event.

Comment: use layout weight for linera layout

Comment: I have View and Linear Layout.

Answer (score 2):

Change ur entire layout as linear layout as this. now add weight accordingly as need.I didnt add weight.this is just a sample code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<View
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#bbbbbb" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The reason that I do not want to convert it to linear layout, because I add a transparent view on the top of `view2` and `view 4` to received gesture event.

Answer (score 1):

To specify percentages, you need to do it programmatically OR you can wrap it in a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the above example, all the `View`s will take equal height in the `LinearLayout`. That means that if the LinearLayout's height is say 300dp, each `View` will have a height of 100dp.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer. I have four views actually one of them is vertically stand (`view1`). Please see my edited question. I have upvoted your effort. In addition to that, I would like to keep `view3` as linearlayout not view.